# Firebase function deploy not working with cross-fetch API

Tags: typescript, firebase

I've posted a question in here a few days back about firebase deploy not working and giving me the "Function failed on loading user code" error. Since that, I've come to a conclusion that the reason why the deploy fails is because I'm using the cross-fetch API to fetch data from API and the firebase deploy has some kind of problem with that (the API and code itself works because I can run it locally and it works). Is that even possible, or is that just my reasoning behind some other, more complicated bug? When I delete the fetch function from my code, it deploys and runs without a problem.

Comment: Hello, do you mind sharing what you have tried so far, and what explicitly is blocking you to make progress?

Comment: Hi @daydreamer, sure. So first I wrote this function which you can check out here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748629/firebase-function-deploy-not-working-with-cross-fetch-api). Even though the function runs locally with firebase serve without a problem, when deploying with firebase deploy, the deployment fails with aforementioned error. Then I tried to deploy a simple function just with writing to firestore  to see whether the problem isn't somewhere else, but deploying functions without the fetch API works great [...]

Comment: [...] So then I read somewhere that the problem could be in Firebase using node12 but me using node15, so I downgraded to node12.21.0. That didnt help either. So again, I tried rewriting and deploying a function which only writes the timestamp to the firestore. That function deployed and runs properly. From that, I concluded that the problem is in the FetchAPI, but I'm new to working with Firebase functions, so I came here to ask if that is even possible.

Comment: @daydreamer sorry, posted a wrong link in the first reply, here is the correct one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66733307/firebase-function-runs-locally-but-deployment-fails